Unexpected return type of a reactive function
Consider the following code:
public static Mono<String> myFunction(boolean condition) {
    if (condition) {
        // returns Mono<String>
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> "Hello, World!"); 
    } else {
        // returns Mono<Void>  
        return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> System.out.println("Running a task...")); 
    }
}

This code compiles and run perfectly fine. Mono.fromSupplier returns String, whereas Mono.fromRunnable returns Mono<Void>, then ideally compilation should fail. What am I missing?

Mono.fromRunnable does not necessarily return Mono<Void>. In fact, it can return Mono<T> for any T.
public static <T> Mono<T> fromRunnable(Runnable runnable)

Because of type inference, it is inferred that you mean Mono.<String>fromRunnable(...).
It creates an empty Mono<String> that completes without emitting any value. Think Mono.empty(), except it runs the Runnable on subscription.

okay I got it. But whats the reasoning behind this? AFAIK Runnable returns nothing.

@Cody yeah it returns nothing. That’s why it creates an empty mono. What reasoning do you need?

The Mono class in Project Reactor is a generic type, and Mono is a subtype of Mono. Although this might sound contradictory, it’s not exactly the case. What happens here is that Mono can be seen as a Mono<?>, which is a type that can represent any kind of Mono, including Mono.
Due to type erasure in Java, and because the Mono does not contain any concrete value (it's a "void" type), the compiler can treat it as if it were a Mono when necessary.
